# return list of objects as strings in react JS

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

i have a list of objects that gets created from a multiselect list on a form. what i would like to do is only return the values from that object list as strings but it does not work the ways i have tried so far. here is what i have and its results.

```
handlePartnerAssociated(option){
    console.log(option)//this returns my objects that looks like [{value:"a", label:"a"}, {value:"b", label:"b"}]
    let new_option = Object.keys(options)
    console.log(new_option)//this returns list of ["0", "1","2"..etc] depending on amount of selections
```

it converts it to numbers and not the letters that i want more specifically how can i just get it to return like this "a", "b", "c"

[console view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wmtq6.png)

Comment: The 'keys' of an array are the array's indices ('0' ... 'N-1'). Use `option.map(o => o.value)` if you want the `value` properties.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`const strings = options.map(({ value }) => value)` will map your array of objects to an array of strings